# Is there a way to load the FULL 3D REAL WORLD TERRAIN into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a High-definition RP flight simulator project in unity, and I want to use a 3d full real world map.
Is there a way to load the FULL 3D REAL WORLD TERRAIN into Unity?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is No, there's no such feature built-in to Unity. It would be a fairly major project to automatically map google maps data or similar into Unity - I suggest googling for existing projects where folks have attempted this.

Comment: Assuming you have a terrain map of the world, having it loaded all at the same time would most likely be infeasible performance wise. So you'd have to come up with a system to selectively load only the nearby terrain.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **FULL 3D REAL WORLD TERRAIN**? There are various ways to import terrain into Unity.

- You can hire a 3D modeller to model you a 3D terrain and import it into your project later on.
- You can import heightmap into Unity and apply it onto a terrain. Later you can add trees, houses etc. on top of it.
- Or you can sculpt it directly inside Unity.